# Returning a microsoft graph event php

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have the following code I am just trying to echo the showAs status from microsoft graph events.  I can return most like subject or body preview I just can't seem to get the showAs status

```
<h3 class="list-group-item-heading"><?php echo $event->getshowAs()->getfreeBusyStatus() ?></h3>
```

The Class is as follows

```
   * Gets the showAs
* The status to show. The possible values are: free, tentative, busy, oof, workingElsewhere, unknown.
*
* @return FreeBusyStatus The showAs
*/
public function getShowAs()
{
    if (array_key_exists("showAs", $this->_propDict)) {
        if (is_a($this->_propDict["showAs"], "Microsoft\Graph\Model\FreeBusyStatus")) {
            return $this->_propDict["showAs"];
        } else {
            $this->_propDict["showAs"] = new FreeBusyStatus($this->_propDict["showAs"]);
            return $this->_propDict["showAs"];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The documentation from them is

showAs  freeBusyStatus  The status to show. The possible values are: free, tentative, busy, oof, workingElsewhere, unknown.

Comment: Could you please share the MS Graph call that you are making, Are you using any 'select' query parameter? Try the MS Graph call in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) and POSTMAN and see if you are getting the 'showAs' property.

Comment: Are you still looking for help?